# Trigger UIPath bot from Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, uipath

Would it be possible to just launch a bot created on `UIPath` via an `Azure Cloud Function`? I read on `UIPath` official documentation that I would probably need the `UIPath orchestrator` but even, how can I trigger my bot from `Azure Function`, if it's possible?

Comment: What is an Azure function for you? You can use the auth via node.js or Rest if you mean that. And that makes it possible to launch a job from wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to trigger an UiPath Orchestrator job from any HTTP Call, you can easily make an HTTP Call to your Orchestrator server from [Power Automate](https://flow.microsoft.com/) (formerly Microsoft Flow) or even Azure Databricks. You can use Postman to test your calls straight away.

First you authenticate via API call, then with the response of the token, you use it as Auth for the following API calls that will, in your case, trigger a process.

You can get help from your server On Premises from the Swagger service https:///swagger/index.html ([more here](https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/reference/api-references))